# Program reads previous input

Tags: c#, console-application

I've just started understanding C# code and wanted to try out a Console Application. Fairly basic, and would involve a loop to carry out some work until the user decides to quit. This is how my program looks for now.

```
public void Method1(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length != 0)
    {
        DoWork(args);
        ResetValues();
        Loop(parameter);                
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No arguments passed");
        string helpMsg ...
        Console.WriteLine(helpMsg);
    }

public void Loop(parameter)
{
    bool wantsContinue = true;

    while (wantsContinue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do now?\n-Exit\tWrite 'e'\n-Run again\tWrite 'r'");
        ConsoleKeyInfo command = Console.ReadKey();
        char key = command.KeyChar;

        switch (key)
        {
            case 'e':
                return;
            case 'r':
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter your commands");                        
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                Method1(parameters);
                break;
            case 'h':
                Console.WriteLine(helpMsg);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("\nInvalid argument. Enter again");
                break;
        }
    }
}

public void MethodContinuous(input)
{
    Console.WriteLine(input);
    string[] args = input.Split(' ');

    if (args.Length != 0)
    {
        DoWork(args);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No arguments passed");
        string helpMsg = ...
        Console.WriteLine(helpMsg);
    }
}
```

However, I am getting a problem which I can't figure out. When the program enters the loop first time, it sets the parameters correctly, but when the loop is continuing, it gives me the user input from the previous run. I'm probably doing something that isn't right, or the Console works a bit differently. Can the expert figure it out?

Comment: So, what is `ProgramLoop()`? What is `ResetValues()`?

Comment: changed it. Basically I set up what I was gonna write beforehand, but thought I got a solution. Changed method names and forgot to update them. ProgramLoop was renamed to just loop. ResetValues just resets the values of my variables, and nothing else. As you can obviously tell, I'm quite a beginner! :(

Comment: Allright, never mind... Still, what happens in these methods? And in `DoWork()`, too? What does your `main` look like? I believe you will eventually kill your stack...

Comment: DoWork basically takes the input from the user and concatenates it. I'm eventually going to turn this into a mathematical tool, but for now concatenating input from the user is what DoWork() does. This is a class seperated from Program class, the object is created by main and main just calls method1 to start off the program.

Comment: Please post the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a `break` after every `case`-Statement

```
switch (key)
    {
        case 'e':
            wantsContinue = false;
            break;
        case 'r':
            Console.WriteLine("\nYippeeee! I get to run again");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your commands");                        
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            Method1(parameters);
            break;
        case 'h':
            Console.WriteLine(helpMsg);
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("\nInvalid argument. Enter again");
            break;
    }
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/06tc147t.aspx):

Execution of the statement list in the selected section begins with the first statement and proceeds through the statement list, typically until a jump statement is reached, such as a break, goto case, return, or throw. At that point, control is transferred outside the switch statement or to another case label.

Comment: Also note that you must have a `break` or a `return` or throw an exception in each case, else you get a compile error.

Comment: You said, "If you don't put a break, the thread of execution will "fall" through the next case until a break or return occurs." That's not true at all. C# does not support "fall through." Without a break or other transfer-of-control, you'll get a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
case 'r':
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your commands");                        
            parameters[0]= Console.ReadLine();
            Method1(parameters);
            break;
```